# Select on change inside bootstrap popover does not fire

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a select that I need to place inside the bootstrap popover

http://jsfiddle.net/BcczZ/155/

```
<div class="settings" data-toggle="popover" data-mysettings="#someid" data-original-title="A Title"> 
   <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
</div>
<div id="someid" style="display: none">
    <select id='list'>
        <option value='1'>First</option>
        <option value='2'>Second</option>
        <option value='3'>Third</option>
    </select>
</div>



<span id="result" />
```

and on change i need to get the values ,  but seems like on.('change'...  does not fire once the element is cloned. Not sure if this is select id issue.

Here is same script with select outside the popover and works fine

http://jsfiddle.net/BcczZ/156/

what am I missing?

Any help is appreciated. thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BcczZ/157/)***

Use event delegation like below.

```
$(document).on('change','#list', function () {
    $('#result').text($('#list option:selected').val());
});
```

Comment: @Benn - great. glad to help. please accept this as the answer when you get a chance.

Comment: you mind giving this a try?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20787435/form-inside-popover-bootstrap-update-original-form-on-popover-hide

Comment: @Krishna Sir I Used Your JS demo to get the value of multiple checkboxes in popover but I get only one value how do I get the all the checked values from that popover. ??

Comment: @ankitsuthar - can you please create a fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/) with all your related HTML and javascript and send me the link? I'll be happy to help.

Comment: @Krishna  Hello sir.  I never created Jsfiddle before so I just put my HTML and js code on it. https://jsfiddle.net/ankit29/uh3ad9ao/

Comment: @ankitsuthar - it's better that you create a new question for this since you'll get a lot more answers for this. I'll give it a try but you'll get a quicker answer if you post a separate question.