# Form inside popover bootstrap update original form on popover hide

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a form inside the bootstrap popover, 
http://jsfiddle.net/BcczZ/185/

```
<div class="settings" data-toggle="popover" data-mysettings="#someid" data-original-title="Settings"> <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>

</div>
<fieldset id="someid" style="display: none">
    <select id='list' class="form-control">
        <option value='1'>First</option>
        <option value='2'>Second</option>
        <option value='3'>Third</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputtext" value="1000">



    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked>One</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2">Two</label>
    </div>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1">1</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox2" value="option2">2</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox3" value="option3">3</label>
         <br /> <br />
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
</fieldset><span id="result" />
```

the issue I am facing is that the original form is hidden on load and shown only inside the popover which is actually cloning the form. After the user edit and popover is closed I need to update the original form elements values.

I dont know what approach to use. I think it would be best if popover would just move the form inside and place it where it was on close. Seems the shortest way.

Any help or idea is appreciated. 
thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else needs this , here it is , 
http://jsfiddle.net/BcczZ/215/

```
var $popoversettings = $('.settings').popover({
    html: true,
    placement: 'right',
    content: function () {
        var mySettings = $(this).data('mysettings'),
            sfieldset = $(mySettings).find('fieldset');

            return $(sfieldset).appendTo($(this));

    }
});


$(':not(#anything)').on('click', function (e) {
    $popoversettings.each(function () {
        if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
            // before hide update original elements

            var placebak = $('.popover-content').find('fieldset');
            var parrent=  $(this).data('mysettings');
            $(placebak).appendTo($(parrent));
            $(this).popover('hide');
            return;
        }
    });
});
```